# How can I transfer integer value from one activity to another?

Tags: java

i'm trying to compile 4 integers from 4 different activities. the first activity is one of the 4 integer. the second activity is where i compile them.. I don't know what's the best way to send a value from different activites. Most of the intent methods i saw uses startActivity but still won't work.

```
public class QuizSecond extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView totalQuestionsTextView2;
TextView questionTextView2;
Button ansA2, ansB2, ansC2, ansD2;
Button submitBtn2;
int score= 0;
int totalQuestion2 = QuestionAnswer2.question2.length;
int currentQuestionIndex2 = 0;
String selectedAnswer2 = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_second);

    totalQuestionsTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.total_question2);
    questionTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.question_preview);
    ansA2 = findViewById(R.id.ans_A2);
    ansB2 = findViewById(R.id.ans_B2);
    ansC2 = findViewById(R.id.ans_C2);
    ansD2 = findViewById(R.id.ans_D2);
    submitBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn2);

    ansA2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansB2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansC2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansD2.setOnClickListener(this);
    submitBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);

    totalQuestionsTextView2.setText("Total questions : "+totalQuestion2);
    loadNewQuestion();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    ansA2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansB2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansC2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansD2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
    if(clickedButton.getId()==R.id.submit_btn2){
        if(selectedAnswer2.equals(QuestionAnswer2.correctAnswers2[currentQuestionIndex2])) {
            score++;


        }
        currentQuestionIndex2++;
        loadNewQuestion();


        Intent quizIntent = new Intent(QuizSecond.this,ComputeActivity.class);
        quizIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_NUMBER",score);



    }
    else{
        //choices button clicked
        selectedAnswer2  = clickedButton.getText().toString();
        clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    }

}

void loadNewQuestion(){

    if(currentQuestionIndex2 == totalQuestion2 ){
        startActivity(new Intent(QuizSecond.this, ComputeActivity.class));

        return;
    }

    questionTextView2.setText(QuestionAnswer2.question2[currentQuestionIndex2]);
    ansA2.setText(QuestionAnswer2.choices2[currentQuestionIndex2][0]);
    ansB2.setText(QuestionAnswer2.choices2[currentQuestionIndex2][1]);
    ansC2.setText(QuestionAnswer2.choices2[currentQuestionIndex2][2]);
    ansD2.setText(QuestionAnswer2.choices2[currentQuestionIndex2][3]);

}
```

}

second activity:

`int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_NUMBER",0); if (number > 3){ Toast.makeText(ComputeActivity.this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();}`

Comment: In think we need see the code for QuizIntent - but also, is it intentional that you `putExtra("TRANSFER_NUMBER"` but `getIntExtra("EXTRA_NUMBER"` ?

Comment: @racraman sorry i got confused, both are the same `"TRANSFER_NUMBER"`  also do you mean the intent or the whole code for the first activity?

Comment: The Intent Class - certainly the putExtra and getIntExtra methodd …. But hold on, in first activity, you have `Intent quizIntent = new Intent`, but you never store that `quizIntent` anywhere - so there’s no way that seconds Activity can be referring to the same instance.

Comment: This link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) should help you.

Comment: @racraman thank you so much, i finally fixed the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Update this

```
Intent quizIntent = new Intent(QuizSecond.this, ComputeActivity.class);
quizIntent.putExtra("TRANSFER_NUMBER", score);
startActivity(quizIntent);
```